# Using Dictionaries for DataGridView in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagridview

I have a Dictionary that I want to display in DataGridView in a WPF App. I have another list with the column headers that I want. The list of doubles is 200 items long, and the headers 201 items long. Im wondering if there is an way of displaying them all in a table ?

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> properties = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
List<string> gPropertyNames = new List<string>();

propertiesDataGrid.ItemsSource = properties;
```

Trying the ToArray() and Values.ToList() after the dictionary name are not helping me. All I see in the datagrid is two columns, Key and Value, with the value column saying (Collection).

I can manually set the column headers in XAML, but if there is an automated way, that would be awesome, especially if I need to change the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can bind rows to a collection but not columns

Create a class with 200 properties like Jacques answer
For the get you would return Value[0],  Value[1], ...
And it can be List

Or you could could build up the columns in code being and in the case you can bind to Value[0],  Value[1], ...

Answer (score 0):

do you need to use some methods specific to the dictionaries ? If not, here is my suggestion :

- Create a class which has a string and a double properties
- Create an ObservableCollection of that class
- Set that collection as the items source of your datagrid.

And that's it ! The headers will be the the name of the properties specified in your class, so easy to change afterward.

Hope it's help

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to be able to search for the properties using the key, but Id rather have it display in the datagrid and have a more complicated search algorithm.